# How to send json data to jQuery.css()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send json formatted data to jQuery.css() function, and i dont know how to do that.
Later on, i will send more properties, this is just example of my problem.

```
//Sorry, this var x is actually string that i get when i print my json string
var x = {"transform":"rotate(30deg)","-o-transform":"rotate(30deg)"}

//If i try to do something like this wont work
$("#mainImage").css(x);


//but following works
$("#mainImage").css({"transform":"rotate(30deg)","-o-transform":"rotate(30deg)"})
```

It probably has to do something that jquery accepts `.css( map )`
A map of property-value pairs to set.

And i am trying to send single text string, can i somehow convert json to map ?

@Pekka Yes, i am sure that `$("#mainImage").css(x);` doesnt work.

@Felix That is what i get by calling `json = JSON.stringify(data);` sorry if it not json data, i am js newbie..

Comment: Strange. `$("#mainImage").css(x); ` should work. Are you 100% sure it doesn't?

Comment: `x` is not JSON. It is a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should parse *not stringify* JSON before. I tried this one It's works.

```
var json = '{ "display": "none" }';
var cssObject = JSON.parse(json);
$("#mainImage").css(cssObject);
```

Comment: I think you can parse with jQuery.parseJSON() to add some more backwards compatibility; JSON.parse() is available only in modern browsers

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var x = {"background-color": "yellow"};
        $('body').css(x);
    });
```

And basically it works. So the problem can be in sth totally different. Maybe your img element is not there?

Comment: Yeah, its there, i should have parsed it first, that is why it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/A4azg/

```
var cssObj = {
      'background-color' : '#ddd',
      'font-weight' : '',
      'color' : 'red',
      "transform":"rotate(30deg)",
      "-o-transform":"rotate(30deg)",
      "-webkit-transform":"rotate(30deg)"
    }
$("#mainImage").css(cssObj);
```